# What is wrong with my code/ what can I do to solve this assignment?

Tags: java

In this lab, you will be creating a program that merges two arrays of positive (greater than 0) integers. Your program will accept each array as input from the keyboard. You do not know ahead of time how many values will be entered, but you can assume each array will have a maximum length of 10,000 elements. To stop entering values enter zero or a negative number. You should disregard any non-positive numbers input and not store these in the array.

The elements of the two input arrays should be in increasing order. In other words, each array element must have a value that is greater than or equal to the previous element value. An array may contain repeated elements.
After the two arrays have been input, your program must check to make sure the elements of each array have been entered in order. If an out of order element is found, print the message “ERROR: Array not in correct order”.

Your task is to merge the two input arrays into a new array, with all elements in order, lowest to highest. Print out each of the original arrays entered, followed by the merged array.
Please note that your program must output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers.

Sample Run 1:

Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit

3

3

5

6

8

9

-1

Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit

3

4

5

6

-5

First Array:

3 3 5 6 8 9

Second Array:

3 4 5 6

Merged Array:

3 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 8 9

My code was:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int one1=0;
      int two1=0;
      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;
      int flag = 0;
      int[]one=new int[10000];
      int[]two=new int[10000];

  System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
  while (a==0){
    int first = scan.nextInt();
    if (first<=0) a++;
    else{
      one[one1]=first;  
    one1++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
  while (b==0){
  int second = scan.nextInt();
  if (second<=0) b++;
    else{
      two[two1]=second; 
    two1++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println("First Array:");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < one1 ; i++){
  System.out.print(one[i]+" ");
  }
  for (int i = 0 ; i < one.length-1 ; i++){
  if (one[i]>one[i+1]) flag++;
  }  
  System.out.println("Second Array:");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < two1 ; i++){
  System.out.print(two[i]+" ");
  }
  for (int i = 0 ; i < two.length-1 ; i++){
  if (two[i]>two[i+1]) flag++;
  }
  int[]combo = new int[one.length+two.length];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < combo.length-1 ; i+=2){
    combo[i]=one[i];
    combo[i+1]=two[i];
  }
  if (flag>0) System.out.println("ERROR: Array not in correct order");
  else{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < combo.length; i++){
    System.out.print(combo[i]+" ");
}
}
}
}
```

This code keeps giving me runtime error- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm getting: Runtime Error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10000
 at Main.main(Main.java:276)
 at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:94)
 at Ideone.test(Main.java:42)
 at Ideone.main(Main.java:29)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include important details like the error message --- they'll never be seen down here in the comments.  Your question should stand on its own.

Comment: One source of your confusion is keeping track of two arrays _and_ the amount of data in each. (The opaque variable names are no help, either.) I suggest you create new `int` arrays of length `one1` and `two1`, and then use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to save the only parts of `one` and `two` you care about. Your new arrays will have _correct_ `.length` fields, and will work with [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-).

Comment: Since the requirement is “your program must output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers”, there isn’t really any point in using `Arrays.toString()` here. Shortening the arrays may or may not be worthwhile; if it is, I recommend `Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`.

Comment: @OleV.V.:  "output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers" --- Good catch.  That said, I did some refactoring before answering (by which point others had already solved it), and I found that getting rid of the C-style array-length variables was a huge help --- it eliminated a whole class of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, your merge algortithm is all wrong. You create an array `combo` of length `one.length + two.length`, that is, 20000 (I think `one1 + two1` should suffice). Then you try to fill the new array by looping through it two elements at a time:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < combo.length - 1; i += 2) {
```

So `i` is 0, 2, 4 etc. through 19998 (the last even number before 20000). Except when it gets 10000, you try to pick out `one[i]`, that is `one[10000]`, which is outside the `one` array. This gives the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

How I found out? The stack trace gives a line number. The line it mentions is

```
        combo[i] = one[i];
```

It also mentioned the number 10000, so I knew this was the value of `i` at this point.

I think that what you were trying to do, was fill elements 0 from `one` and `two` into elements 0 and 1 of `combo`, I think it works so far. Then you wanted to fill element 1 from each array into elements 2 and 3; but since you have added 2 to i, you fill in element 2 from each source array and never use element 1 from them. Or any element from odd indices.

Before you mend that problem, allow me to mention one more thing. I think with your logic, input arrays `2 5` and `11 30` will come out as `2 11 5 30`. This doesn’t fulfil “with all elements in order, lowest to highest”. So I think you should think your algorithm over.

Answer (score 0):

the code exist many logic error, 

as for **Runtime Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10000 at..**

the problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < combo.length-1 ; i+=2){
    combo[i]=one[i];
    combo[i+1]=two[i];
}
```

the `i from 0 to 19999` and the index of `a,b` is *from 0 to 9999*, and the code exist other `simple logic problem`. Please check it again.

Answer (score -1):

Homework questions are very frowned upon, but still, Java is a relatively easy language. If your program is throwing a RuntimeException, you just have to read what the problem is.

In this case, it seems a loop iterates more times than it should, and you are accessing other memory space. Give it a few reads with the info provided by the error trace in mind.